# Java regex to detect semver strings is failing without qualifiers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get a Java method to validate whether or not a `String` argument is a properly-formatted "*semver*" (semantic versioning) version string.

In my app, semver strings must be of the form:

```
<major>.<minor>.<patch>-<qualifier>
```

Where:

- `<major>` is a positive integer (1+)
- `<minor>` and `<patch>` are both non-negative integers (0+)
- `<qualifier>` is an alphanumeric string (`([0-9][a-z][A-Z])+`)

Valid examples:

- `1.2.40`
- `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`
- `2.0.45-RC`
- `3.10.0`

My best attempt thus far:

```java
public boolean isSemVer(String version) {
    Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z-]+\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = versionPattern.matcher(version);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Produces `false` for the first valid example of `1.2.40`. Can anyone tell me where I'm going awry and what I need to *tweak* in my regex to get it to accept my use cases? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `[a-zA-Z-]+` at the start? Your valid examples start with digits.

Comment: Looks like you need `Pattern.compile("[1-9]\\d*\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your valid strings start with digits and not with letters, so `[a-zA-Z-]+` in your pattern already makes the pattern wrong.

Use

```
^[1-9]\d*\.\d+\.\d+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jjIQfL/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start  of string
- `[1-9]\d*` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then 0 or more digits
- `\.\d+\.\d+` - two occurrences of `.` and 1+ digits (can be written as `(?:\.\d+){2}`)
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of `-` and 1+ alphanumeric chars (`[a-zA-Z0-9]` can be written as `\p{Alnum}`)
- `$` - end of string.

In Java, use with `.matches()`:

```
public boolean isSemVer(String version) {
    Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9]\\d*\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?");
    Matcher matcher = versionPattern.matcher(version);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the official [SemVer regex](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string)

```
"^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"gm
```